# How to prevent 'undefined' data string while reading data from stream?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

Not sure if question is formulated correctly, but here is what I'm talking about.

I have this task:

> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the
>   URLs an d print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print
>   out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch
>   is that you must prin t them out in the same order as the URLs are
>   provided to you as command-line  arguments.

And my solution is working almost as it should, but when I'm outputting stream data as a string it adds 'undefined' to the beginning of the data.

Like this:

> 1. ACTUAL:    "undefinedShe'll be right piker heaps lets throw a chook. As cunning as a bog standard when we're going roadie. Mad as a
>      ratbag with it'l l be outback. Lets get some grog heaps it'll be two
>      up. Gutful of no dramas how stands out like a pav. "
> 2. EXPECTED:  "She'll be right piker heaps lets throw a chook. As cunning a s a bog standard when we're going roadie. Mad as a ratbag
>      with it'll be outb ack. Lets get some grog heaps it'll be two up.
>      Gutful of no dramas how stand s out like a pav. "

And here is how I'm processing stream data:

```
http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function(res) {

res.setEncoding('utf8');

res.on('data', function(data) {
  dataArr[i] += data;
});

res.on('end', function() {
  count++;
  if (count == process.argv.length - 2) {
    printResults(dataArr);
  }
});
```

So I have `dataArr` which is an array where I store collected data, by additional assignment of received `data`. But for some reason it adds `undefined` at the beginin

Comment: if(typeof data !=='undefined'){....}

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It didn't help, I still get same results.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it like

```
if(typeof yourVar[index]!= "undefined"){
 print(sth);
}
```

Comment: what does print do here?

Comment: I just used as placeholder. Place your function here like that yours:
   `printResults(dataArr);`
I fixed a little to != instead ==

Comment: It doesn't work, It looks like empty array element will have 'undefined' value by default, and it won't be replaced when you add data with ```+=```